# magento2 - I want to move this links from default message area to this area, I use luma theme

Tags: magento2, luma-theme

I want to move this links from default message area to this area, I use luma theme
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create this file in your theme.

```
 <magento-root>/app/design/frontend/<vendor-name>/<theme-name>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
```

then add below code:

```
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout  /etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="register-link" destination="header-wrapper" after="-"/>
        <move element="authorization-link" destination="header-wrapper" after="register-link"/>
        <move element="wish-list-link" destination="header-wrapper" after="authorization-link"/>
        <move element="my-account-link" destination="header-wrapper" after="wish-list-link"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Clear the **cache** then check it, let me if you have issue..

Comment: glad to hear that